# ACF Field wont show up via jQuery and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, advanced-custom-fields

I'm currently at a loss on how to do this. I want the title to dynamically change based on the city selected from a dropdown select box named with the id "#city_name". This is currently my code:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery)
    {
        jQuery("select[name='selectyourcity']").change(function()
        {
            var selectedid = jQuery("select[name='selectyourcity']").val();
            jQuery("#city_name").html('<?php the_field("name", '+selectedid+');?>');
        })
    });
```

This does not display the data I need from the ACF field I made. The thing is, I've tested "selectedid" and it does work and returns the id I want. I tested it with this:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery)
    {
        jQuery("select[name='selectyourcity']").change(function()
        {
            var selectedid = jQuery("select[name='selectyourcity']").val();
            jQuery("#city_name").html(selectedid);
        })
    });
```

I also tried placing in the id directly into the PHP part and it works too:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery)
    {
        jQuery("select[name='selectyourcity']").change(function()
        {
            var selectedid = jQuery("select[name='selectyourcity']").val();
            jQuery("#city_name").html('<?php the_field("name", 746);?>');
        })
    });
```

I can't pinpoint what is wrong. I believe its something with adding the string in with the variable.

Here's the HTML Code for the select dropdown, or at least a part of it.

```
<select name="selectyourcity" class="">
       <option value="placeholder" selected disabled >Select your city</option>
       <?php
       $counter=0;
       $args = array(
       'post_type' => 'event_cities',
       'posts_per_page'=> -1,
       'orderby'  => array( 
              'title'  => 'ASC',
             ),
       );
       $query = new WP_Query( $args );
       while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
             $query->the_post();
             ?><option value="<?php echo get_the_id();?>"><?php the_field('name');?></option><?php
                     $counter = $counter + 1;
             }
             wp_reset_postdata();
             ?>
</select>
```

This generates the following code:

```
<select name="selectyourcity" class="">
       <option value="placeholder" selected="" disabled="">Select your city</option>
       <option value="746">Bogotá</option>
       <option value="636">Medellín</option>
</select>
```

I want to insert the title for an ACF field named 'name' here:

```
<div data-element="text" class="cityTitle cs-preview-element-wrapper">
       <div class="x-text cs-ta-center">
              <h4 id="city_name">Name goes here</h4>
       </div>
</div>
```

Comment: just add your html code too!

Comment: hope you know php is a server side language means it executes only in server where as js is client side. when your jquery change function is triggered no way php executes then unless you make an ajax call to a php script!

Comment: Alright Ill try and go about it via ajax

Comment: If you just add your html part maybe i'll be able to help and based on your question i don't think ajax is actually necessary here.

Comment: html part of your code which include the select box and the title which you want to change dynamically...just add this.